# LINQ to SQL error

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a form in which I am able to list a parent table using datagridview. I also have a child payment table that list all the payments made. I have added a combo box so I can make my search more efficient. Everythhing worked great until I added to box. Now I get this error==

InValidCastException == Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.

Can you please helpme correct this?? I am using SQL Server 2005 and Visual Studios 2008.

Dim teamList = From Bowler In Db.Bowlers _
       Where Bowler.TeamNumber <> "" _
       Order By Bowler.TeamNumber _
       Select Bowler.TeamNumber
        For Each TeamNumber In teamList
            Me.ToolStripComboBox1.Items.Add(TeamNumber)
        Next
    End Sub

Thanks Cheryl

Answer (score 2):

I assume Bowler.TeamNumber is a Double datatype.  This means you cannot do

```
Bowler.TeamNumber <> ""
```

instead you can only do

```
Bowler.TeamNumber <> 0
```

or

```
Bowler.TeamNumber <> NULL
```

EDIT: Following on from comment, you need something like this:

```
Dim teamList = (From Bowler In Db.Bowlers _ 
Where Bowler.TeamNumber <> "" _ 
Order By Bowler.TeamNumber _ 
Select Bowler.TeamNumber ).Distinct()

For Each TeamNumber In teamList 
Me.ToolStripComboBox1.Items.Add(TeamNumber) 
Next
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I put the "0" everywhere but there.That work great. I can now see the numbers. But, it is now doubling the numbers. There are 4 bowlers per team which means the number "1" will show up 4 times. And it does not populate the grids with info that is in there. Any suggestions. heryl

Comment: Thank you. It now only show one number. It is still not populating the tables. Any suggestions?

Comment: I git it working.Thanks for your help. Chery
Dim bowlerQuery = From Bowler In Db.Bowlers _
                          Where Bowler.TeamNumber = Me.ToolStripComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() _
                          Select Bowler
        Me.BowlerBindingSource.DataSource = bowlerQuery